# Проблема с получением названия фильма через API

Tags: android, kotlin, api, arraylist

у меня возникла проблема, не понимаю как можно получать название фильма (title) из List

пробывал так: movieName.text = MovieDTO.item?.get(0)?.title - но проблема в том что он выводит только один фильм когда для каждого CardView мне нужны разные фильмы

```
class DetailsFragment : Fragment(){
private var _binding :  FragmentDetailsBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!

private lateinit var moviBundle : Movie

private val onLoaderListener : MovieLoader.MovieLoaderListener =
    object : MovieLoader.MovieLoaderListener {
        override fun onLoaded(movieDTO: MovieDTO) {
            displayMovie(movieDTO)
        }

        override fun onFailed(throwable: Throwable) {
            Snackbar.make(binding.mainView, "Loaded Failed", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
        }
    }

companion object{
    const val BUNDLE_EXTRA = "movie"

    fun newInstance(bundle: Bundle) : DetailsFragment {
        val fragment = DetailsFragment()
        fragment.arguments = bundle
        return fragment
    }
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = FragmentDetailsBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    moviBundle = arguments?.getParcelable<Movie>(BUNDLE_EXTRA) ?: Movie()

    with(binding) {
        mainView.visibility = View.GONE
        loadingLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    }

    val loader = MovieLoader(onLoaderListener, moviBundle.lang, moviBundle.stat)
    loader.loadMovie()
}

override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    _binding = null
}

///// !
private fun displayMovie(movieDTO: MovieDTO) {
    with(binding) {


        mainView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        loadingLayout.visibility = View.GONE


        movieName.text = movieDTO.items?.get(0)?.title
        movieReleseDate.text = movieDTO.items?.get(0)?.releaseState
        movieTime.text = movieDTO.items?.get(0)?.runtimeStr
        movieDescription.text = movieDTO.items?.get(0)?.plot
        movieOriginalName.text = movieDTO.items?.get(0)?.fullTitle

    }
} } <- на это не обращайте внимание
```

Comment: [как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Так `MovieDTO.item?.get(1)?.title` вернет следующий и т.д. Проблема-то в чем?

Comment: да, но тогда на всех будут 2 фильм

Comment: @TTXSTM если правильно вас понял то вам нужно переписать функцию `onLoaded` в `MovieLoaderListener` так что бы можно было еще помимо `MovieDTO` передавать позицию, так же и в `displayMovie` - и тогда использовать `MovieDTO.item?.get(position)?.title`